# Why can't I get the return value from a method in another class if it isn't static?

Tags: java, interface, static

I am just learning about interfaces, and I am trying to toy around with them a bit. I noticed that you cannot make a method static in an interface. I went along my happy way, but when I tried getting the return value of one of my methods from another class, I noticed I couldn't. Consider this a dumb question if you will, is it applies to Java in general as well, but I am not exactly advanced when it comes to programming in this languages. This is my interface:

```
public interface Item 
{
     boolean organia();
}
```

Class implementing the interface:

```
public class Car 
{
     @Override
     public boolean organia() 
     {
         return false;
     }
}
```

Class with main method:

```
public class Main 
{
    static Car car;

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        System.out.println(car.organia());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Of course you can - you just need to create an object ;)

Comment: You're getting some good answers, I honestly think you might be skipping some chapters. Take a step back and learn about Classes and how to create an instance of one before delving into more advanced topics such as inheritance.

Comment: Just curious why he got thumbs down.  Just because it was an 'obvious' question to most doesn't mean it was a bad one.

Answer (score 2):

To call an instance method, you need to make an instance.

```
System.out.println( new car().organia();
```

Frequently you'll want to keep a reference to the new instance.

```
car mycar = new car();
System.out.println( mycar.organia() );
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I think the problem was that I was used to calling methods from within the same class using 'new randomMethod()' and figured that the () was only referring to methods, and not classes as well. To be honest I have no idea what I was thinking. Thanks a bunch though!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that 'new' requires a class or interface name. Following standard Java style can help keep this straight - classes and interfaces begin with an uppercase character, and methods with a lowercase character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your variable:

```
static car car = new car();
```

Then your code will run OK.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, where is your instance for the class? You can't call an instance method without the instance :)

```
Car car = new Car();
System.out.println(car.oragania());
```

should do what you want.

Or you can also initialize your static car variable

```
static Car car = new Car();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Car class needs to implement your Item interface
2. Car name usually is uppercase by convention
3. When you want to call organia method, you need to either create a new Item() or new Car()

   ```
   public class Car implements Item {
          @Override
          public boolean organia() {
               return false;
   }


   public class Main {

       public static void main(String args[]) {
           System.out.println(new Item().organia());
           System.out.println(new Car().organia());
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

An interface is simply a description of what a class should implement

```
public class Car implements Item {
       @Override
       public boolean organia() {
           return false;
}
```

Even if you create a static version of the class (you don't need to, you can just create it in your Main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
Car car = new Car()
    System.out.println(car.organia());
}
```

Good luck!